# Sharepoint file sync error: all my files show 'server file updated'

Tags: sync, office365, sharepoint-2013

I've created a Document Library on Office 365 Sharepoint, added a whole bunch of files (~1.5GB), and synced them to Sharepoint. Then when adding another large set of files to another Document Library the Office/Sharepoint (or whatever other names it goes by) tool crashes, fails to recover the Office Document Cache, creates a new one, and now all/most of my documents are appearing as error items in the Office Upload Center with error message 'Server file updated'. The server and workstation files have a timestamp 1hr difference, possibly because I'm in GMT+1 timezone? Several other users have synced the Document Library to their workstations and might have edited one or two files but not the hundreds or thousands that are erroring.

How can I resolve this, without individually stepping through each file and choosing to retain the server version?

Given the problems I've had with syncing I'm not convinced that all the files have successfully uploaded to Sharepoint so I'm reluctant to drop the sync folder on my workstation and sync again from the sharepoint site ... or is that my best bet?

Also, is it normal to have the Office Document Cache crash regularly and need to rebuild, and will my other users have the same problems? Perhaps Sharepoint just isn't up to the task of dealing with such sized folders and I should use a different tool?

UPDATE: 
I've moved all the files from my synced folder to a regular folder and am attempting to re-sync from the server. Now for some reason when I click the SYNC link in Office 365 in Chrome I get a Sharepoint Workspace tool that isn't the normal thing which comes up when I click the SYNC link. I started syncing with that and it seemed to have some problems so I Disconnected the folder (where it was syncing to I don't know; I never gave it a path) and then opened Office 365 in IE and clicked SYNC. SkyDrive Pro (one of those other names for Groove / Office / Sharepoint ??) pops up and says it'll sync to my folder location, I agree, and after a minute or so it says 'We couldn't sync this library' with Unspecified error and error code 0x800004005; Error source=Groove.

Helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to

1. copy all my files to normal windows folders,
2. remove the SkyDrive synced folders from my machine - i.e. stop syncing them then delete them.
3. delete the folder c:\users[me]\appdata\local\microsoft\office\15.0 so it removed any cache files and old databases.
4. restart
5. re-sync the document libraries to my machine
6. use Total Commander to compare the old and new folders to check I hadn't lost anything.

The sync to re-download all the files from sharepoint went pretty quickly ... although MSOSYNC.EXE is still inexplicably taking 25-50% cpu at all times even when all my folders are synced. I no longer have an Office Upload Center error message for every one of my files!